# React and Zend Framework 3 layout

Tags: php, html, reactjs, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I'm actually starting to use React and I want to integrate to my project that is made with ZF3.

I want to manage the layout of the project with React but i don't understand how manage the content of the templates since that content is on a variable of the layout named $content

Which is the best approach to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was watching some videos of how to integrate react with php and I think that you would need to use zf3 as an api (It is supported using AbstractRestfulController)

React would run as an independent system and call zf3 api when it is needed via ajax